# "matrafia" é uma palavra da língua portuguesa?"

Tags: definição

Encontrei a palavra na seguinte frase escrita em pt-PT: "E estava a pensar, vale a pena ser honesto quando se pode fazer matrafia e vencer?"

Procurei o significado no Aurélio, no Priberam, no Aulete, e no Léxico.pt mas o verbete não aparece em nenhum deles. Contudo, uma busca no Google mostra várias entradas para a palavra, em línguas portuguesa e francesa, além do latim. Pelo contexto, parece que significa "ser desonesto" de alguma forma, mas isso é uma conjectura.

Afinal, "matrafia" é considerada uma palavra da língua portuguesa?  Ou seria um estrangeirismo?  Como é pronunciada? (ma-tra-fia ou ma-tra-fi-a? oxítona, paroxítona ou proparoxítona?)

EDIT - Se eu estiver certo em relação ao significado, em pt-BR temos a palavra "maracutaia" que me parece significar a mesma coisa. E também a expressão "fazer uma maracutaia"

- maracutaia - substantivo feminino  B infrm. negócio escuso, manobra ilícita, esp. em política ou administração; traficância, fraude, falcatrua.

Comment: Nunca ouvi isso. De fato, pelo contexto da frase, parece maracutaia. Já vi usarem "treta" com esse significado também.

Comment: @eightShirt   A frase é de Portugal.

Comment: https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/matrafia-matraficematrificio-matrafisga-reginalismo-alentejano/34128

Comment: @BrunoCosta   Não responde a minha pergunta no que toca a se é um estrangeirismo (uma vez que existe também em textos em francês e latim) se pode ser considerada uma palavra da língua portuguesa, e a forma como é pronunciada. O significado, pelo contexto eu até consigo perceber, conforme escrevi no corpo da pergunta.

Comment: @Centaurus nunca ouvi a palavra, e é a primeira vez que a ouço, pelo sentido da frase é mesmo "maracutaia".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Matrafia, matrafice*** e ***matrafisga*** são regionalismos do sul de Portugal, e aparecem usados com o significado de ‘truque’, ‘artimanha’, 'batota', ‘logro’ e, segundo alguns, ‘bruxaria’, ‘bruxedo’, e ‘maldade’. Eu não conhecia qualquer destas palavras, mas contactando a autora [deste artigo](https://policiariodebolso.blogspot.pt/2012/01/roubo-no-dia-de-reis.html), fiquei a saber que *matrafia* é de uso corrente na região de Santarém (do Ribatejo), e que se aplica sobretudo a esquemas a roçar o ilegal com o obtetivo de enganar ou obter proveitos. *Matrafice* também é lá conhecida entre as pessoas mais velhas.

*Matrafia* ocorre raramente também no Google como transliteração do árabe, em que parece ser nome de [pessoa](https://books.google.pt/books?id=4DCPBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA224&dq=matrafia&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiezbuC67TQAhVESRoKHb7fAgkQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=matrafia&f=false) e parte do [nome de um clã sudanês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawazma_tribe). Também existe o nome [*Matrafi*](http://www.namespedia.com/details/Matrafi). Aparecem algumas *matrafias* em textos doutras línguas na página de resultados do Google Books, mas são erros de reconhecimento de caráter. Por exemplo a ‘*matrafia*’ [desta recolha de poesia provençal](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&espv=2&biw=1242&bih=580&tbm=bks&q=%22fi%D0%B5ou%20tant%20matrafia%22&oq=%22fi%D0%B5ou%20tant%20matrafia%22&gs_l=serp.3...10134.12591.0.12939.2.2.0.0.0.0.96.179.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.0.0.Hb41EE7JUWA), clicando no link, revela-se afinal ser [*matraſſa*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=EdtVAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA49&dq=%22fi%D0%B5ou%20tant%20matrafia%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNj9yM9LTQAhVMvRoKHTd1CucQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22fi%D0%B5ou%20tant%20matrafia%22&f=false), ou *matrassa* escrita com os ss longos doutros tempos.

Encontrei na net dezanove ocorrências independentes de *matrafia*, sempre assim grafada, nunca *matráfia* ou *matrafiá*. Logo é paroxítona, com acento tónico em *fi* (rima com *caligrafia*); a menos que toda a gente tenha escrito mal. *Matrafice* e *matrafisga* também aparecem sempre assim grafadas, e estão registadas em dicionários de regionalismos [(Ciberdúvidas)](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/matrafia-matraficematrificio-matrafisga-reginalismo-alentejano/34128): portanto têm também acento tónico no *fi*.

O [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/matrafia-matraficematrificio-matrafisga-reginalismo-alentejano/34128) dá conta também das variantes *matrifício* e *matrifícia* em dicionários portugueses, mas eu não encontrei estas palavras na net. Encontrei sim ***matrafício***, mas apenas em dois sites independentes. [Populu, um dicionário online,](http://populu.net/matraficio) dá *matrafício* como um termo alentejano com o significado de  ‘malefício’, ‘bruxaria’, ‘bruxedo’, ‘maldade’ e ‘matrafice’. [Neste glossário de termos alentejanos](http://www.joraga.net/pdf/_Alentejo_PalavraseExpressoes_201104_img_60p.pdf), *matraficio* aparece também como sinónimo de *matrafice*, com o significado de ‘artimanha’ e ‘bruxaria’. Dá também *mastrola* como sinónimo de ‘engano’ e ‘matrafice’.

Agora, nos exemplos de uso o significado destas palavras é sempre ‘artimanha’, ‘truque’, ‘batota’, ‘logro’, ‘vigarice’. Alguns exemplos de ***matrafia*** (ênfase minha):

> Face a tantas mentiras alguém pode dizer que as votações para a Presidência são os votos reais??? Ou é mais alguma **matrafia**. O problema está ai.Com tanta mentira LFV [Luís Filipe Vieira, dirigente do Benfica] não assegura que as eleições sejam mesmo verdadeiras e não um embuste e manipuladas para que ganhe ele [(Blog *Geração Benfica*, 2015.)](http://geracaobenfica.blogspot.com/2015/01/quando-boca-fugiu-para-verdade.html)
>
> Como não me inscrevi não dispendi os 11 euricos da inscrição, que verdade seja dita são mais bem empregues em qualquer petiscada ou incursão gastronómica. Mas comecei a arrebanhar quase os mesmos brindes que o resto dos milhares de pessoas […] Mas a grande questão é: inscrever-me para quê quando se pode fazer  **matrafia** e ganhar o mesmo que os outros?
>   [(Blog *Guia de Campo*, 2007.)](http://guiadecampo.blogspot.pt/2007_03_01_archive.html)

Nestes outros exemplos, *matrafia* significa ‘truque’ no sentido de ‘jeito’, não de ‘engano’:

> o que vem a seguir é que foi chato! até o estrado tivemos que montar…. uff foi uma coisa…o primeiro custou mas o segundo já foi rápido… pois já sabiamos a **matrafia**!
>   [(“A montagem [de uma cama] continua”, *Cruz’s Weblog*, 2008.)](https://cruzs.wordpress.com/)
>
> Parece que afinal o IE não gosta do swffit! A minha aplicação não é carregada no IE sempre que uso o swffit.
>   Há alguma **matrafia** para que funcione naquela porcaria de browser (tinha de ser ele a dar cabo de tudo)? [(Google Groups, 2015.)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/riapt/1uEt43rhUlU/nzfu9tQKdKwJ)

Exemplos de ***matrafice***:

> Que este forum é encarnado [do Benfica] já todos sabemos, mas vivemos em democracia as regras existem para quem tem o queijo mas também exstem para quem tem a faca, já o Batalha foi banido por uma **matrafice** de alguém com poder cá dentro que escreveu em nome dele, se quizerem podem me banir também e ficarem cá só os vermelhos felizes e contentes
>   [(*GForum*, 2009.)](http://www.geralforum.com/board/showthread.php/18647-a-toca-do-keao-sportinnnnggg-/page28)
>
> Desde sempre a TVI manipulou este tipo de programas [reality shows em que se vota para expulsar concorrentes…] E a prova disto é que as votações online, durante o dia de ontem, estiveram suspensas na maior parte do dia! Porquê? Porque estava a haver "**matrafice**" no votos, óbvio...
>   [(“Eu e os reality shows”, blog *Opiniões em teia*, 2012.)](https://opinioesemteia.blogspot.pt/2012/11/eu-e-os-reality-shows.html)
>
> Actualmente, existe uma ferramenta q, supostamente, é só para maiores de 18; desbloquear o perfil para ser seguido por outras pessoas. Só q, hoje em dia, os "adolescentes" fazem uma **matrafice** qualquer lá no perfil e já conseguem ser seguidos antes de terem 18 anos
>   [(Blog *A Resmungona*, 2014.)](http://aresmungona.blogs.sapo.pt/selfies-ou-belfies-2331)

E para não alongar ainda mais, e como uma imagem vale por mil palavras, aqui fica um único exemplo de ***matrafisga*** do [Blog do Gervásio](https://blogdogervazio.wordpress.com/2011/02/05/matrafisga-do-dia/):

[image]

Comment: Excelente dissertação.  Aceito muito satisfeito embora uma das perguntas não tenha sido respondida (uma vez que não consta nos dicionários, podemos considerar "matrafia" uma palavra da língua portuguesa?)

Comment: Muito interessante.  Interessante também que Portugal sendo um país pequeno, poucos (ou talvez ninguém por aqui) tivessem ouvido a palavra anteriormente.

Comment: Uma pergunta sobre esta frase: "Como não me inscrevi não dispendi os 11 euricos da inscrição, que verdade seja dita são mais bem empregues em qualquer petiscada"  "Euricos" (acredito ser um diminutivo para Euros) e "empregues" são de uso corrente?  "empregues" é gramatical em pt-PT?

Comment: Realmente, agora que li tua resposta, acho que "matrafia" tem realmente um sonoridade árabe.

Comment: Jacinto,  se dois deles mentem e só um fala a verdade, quem comeu a fruta foi o Baltazar.

Comment: @Centaurus Eu entendi a pergunta se *matrafia* é considerado língua portuguesa por oposição a estrangeirismo. Tendo posto de parte esta última hipótese, não achei proveitoso estar a discutir os requisitos de pertença à língua. Para mim, estar num dicionário não é requisito. É um regionalismo. Quão localizado, não sei dizer. Eu cresci a uns 50 km de Santarém, e não conhecia a palavra. A pessoa que eu contactei ficou surpreendida por a palavra não estar no dicionário. Baltazar foi também a minha resposta, mas não tive prémio nenhum! *Empregue(s)* (=*utilizado*) é empregue por aqui, sim.

Comment: @Centaurus sim, "euricos" é gíria corrente, e "empregar" é uso não-gíria ainda mais comum (ver #4 em http://priberam.pt/dlpo/empregar ) - como disse o Jacinto.

Comment: É eu nunca tinha ouvido/visto essa palavra na minha vida.

Comment: @ANeves "euricos" nunca ouvi tal coisa. "Euritos" sim.

Comment: @JorgeB.  E o que são "Euritos"?

Comment: @Centaurus são euros. "Tens aí dois euritos que me emprestes?"

Comment: @JorgeB.  Infelizmente é final de mês e estou "duro".  Eu estava pensando em pedi-los a ti.